# Adding several new sheets to workbook with xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel

I am extracting data from different columns in several EXCEL files and would like to write the results to several sheets in a new workbook with `xlsxwriter` in Python 3.

For this purpose, I am writing my results to lists of lists and then try to write each list of lists to a new sheet with a new, distinct name.

The first new sheet I am trying to write is this:

```
with xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:\\Users\\###\\NewEntities.xlsx') as workbook:  #generate file xlsx
    worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet("PERSONS")
    for row_num, data in enumerate(pers_list_new):
        try:
            worksheet1.write_row(row_num, 0, data)
        except:
            pass
```

The last one is this:

```
    worksheet5 = workbook.add_worksheet("INSTITUTIONS")

    for row_num, data in enumerate(inst_list_new):
        try:
            worksheet5.write_row(row_num, 0, data)
        except:
            pass
```

The new EXCEL file is created correctly, but only the INSTITUTIONS list (worksheet 5) are visible in the output file. It seems that `xlswriter` is not adding a new worksheet for each list at all but rather overwriting existing worksheets so that only the one written to the file last remains. As I have used different variables for the new worksheets and given them new names, I am at a loss why this happens.

Checking the `xlswriter` documentation, I could unfortunately not find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. Here is a working example based on your code:

```py
import xlsxwriter

pers_list_new = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]] * 5
inst_list_new = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]] * 5

with xlsxwriter.Workbook('NewEntities.xlsx') as workbook:
    worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet("PERSONS")
    for row_num, data in enumerate(pers_list_new):
        try:
            worksheet1.write_row(row_num, 0, data)
        except:
            pass

    worksheet5 = workbook.add_worksheet("INSTITUTIONS")
    for row_num, data in enumerate(inst_list_new):
        try:
            worksheet5.write_row(row_num, 0, data)
        except:
            pass
```

Output, showing more than one worksheet:

[image]

Comment: I accidentally re-opened the whole workbook again along the way... so this is why the sheets were over-written. Deleting this fixed it all!